# Mat-Datepicker custom component ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked Error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor, mat-datepicker

I am making a custom datepicker component so it can work with localization and moment.js, and also with reactive forms.

I have set up the component but after DateChange event, after it exits the zone, it throws an error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.
```

At this moment I am out of the ideas how to fix it though I tried to fix it with `ChangeDetectorRef` which makes my validation untriggerable, and similar stuff happens with `this.control.updateValueAndValidty()`.

After all, it happens a lot later than I can trigger anything. I suppose it's input element problem, so I'll try to catch its change event in the meantime.

So this is `date-picker.component.ts`:

```
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input, Self, Optional, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, NgControl, FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import { MatDatepickerInputEvent, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment';
const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

export const DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY.',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY.',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};


@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'sr' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DATE_FORMATS }
  ]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  control: FormControl;
  private onChange = (value: any) => { };
  private onTouched = (value: any) => { };
  @Input() dateValue: string = null;
  @Input() errorMessage: string = "This is required.";
  @Input() public placeholder: string = null;
  @Input() public minDate: string = null;
  @Input() public maxDate: string = null;
  @Input() public startDate: string = null;
  @Input() public label: string = null;

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() private ngControl: NgControl, @Optional() private controlName: FormControlName, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    if(this.ngControl != null) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    moment.locale('sr');
    this.control = this.controlName.control;
  }

  onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.dateValue = moment(event.value).format();
    this.onChange(event.value);
  }

  // get errorState() {
  //   debugger;

  //   if(!this.dateValue){
  //     return this.ngControl.errors !== null && !!this.ngControl.touched;
  //   }
  //   return false;
  // }

  // ControlValueAccessor methods
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if(value !== undefined || value !== '') {
      this.dateValue = moment(value).format();
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}
  // registerOnTouched(fn) {
  //   this.onTouched = fn;
  // }


}
```

And this is `date-picker.component.html`:

```
<div class="date-picker">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">

      <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
      <input #dpInput matInput
        [matDatepicker]="componentDatePicker"
        (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)"
        [formControl]="control"
        [value]="dateValue"
        [min]="minDate"
        [max]="maxDate"
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
        [formControl]='control'>

      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="componentDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #componentDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
      <mat-error [innerHTML]="errorMessage"></mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And I am changing the `min` and `max` values in the parent component by returning the `new Date(year, month, day)` object with values or `null`. There are multiple instances of the same picker so I'm sending the string value to differentiate between them.

```
<app-date-picker
   [minDate]="getMinDate('datepickerIdentifier')"
   [maxDate]="getMaxDate('datepickerIdentifier')"
   [placeholder]="'Placeholder string'"
   [label]="'Label string'"
   [errorMessage]="'Error string'"
   formControlName="applicationEnd"
   required>
 </app-date-picker>
```

I was trying to build reusable datepicker component which will have localization, specific date format, and that it can be easily incorporated in the reactive forms so i can validate it with the rest of the form data, and show `Validation.required` errors.

Unfortunately I have no idea where to begin to debug this.

EDIT: I tried to make a stackblitz but it kinda gives me lot of errors but nonetheless here it is:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aylptw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I have achieved it

This `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked` is thrown when an expression in your HTML has changed after Angular has already checked or compared `oldValue !== newValue`. Make your change detection strategy to `onPush` like the following way and trigger the manual change detection just like explained in the last code snippet.

```
@Component({
                   ...                   
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

You are following the Angular material documentation, it is good.

```
import { MatDateFormats } from '@angular/material/core'; //import MatDateFormats 

export const APP_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
parse: {
  dateInput: 'MM/DD/YYYY', //whichever format you are tyring, define here
},
display: {
  dateInput: 'MM/DD/YYYY', //change accordingly, to display
  monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
  dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
  monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  }
};
```

Please try to create the above code in a different file, it's easier to maintain.

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { APP_DATE_FORMATS } from '../../helpers/datepicker.format';
import { MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter'; 
//register the imports respectively which are going to be addressed in providers

    
providers: [
  { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },
  {
    provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS,
    deps: [
     MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
     MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Update your respective module providers as above and do your reactive form validations, If you encounter `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked` then define the following `ChangeDetectorRef` from `angular/core to solve in the respective component. Thanks.

```
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
        
insideYourValidations() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this._cdr.detectChanges() //call to update/detect your changes
 }, 1500);
}
```

Sometimes when we get the `ExpressionchangeError` the datepicker might not update the date value, with the `ChangeDetectorRef` the form input values are updated if user tries to input manually without using datepicker.

This [helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862350/6421690) me, fix my problem. [zmag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3870547/zmag) Thanks

Comment: Is there a special reason for the timeout here?

Comment: Please read https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/ for better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.dateValue = moment(event.value).format();
    this.onChange(event.value); <= THIS WAS THE PROBLEM
  }
```

Seemingly, after removing `this.onChange(event.value)`, both validation and component started working pretty fine.

EDIT: It has removed other problems I had with it, but still throws a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.`

Comment: With my above solution, the date you entered will be a moment converted date and you do not have to reformat it in your `onDateChange()`. I know it's almost a year but this will work 100%

Comment: @Manoj thank you for your help! I didn't quite get the concept Change Detection strategy  seems like it. Now I can see, with your help,  that this was exactly what I was looking for just didn't find/used the onPush method.

Fortunately, I might need this now so thank you for the great answer :D