# Angular 8 value won't update on view after change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I have a small component in Angular with a method that (for now) sets a timeout and changes the value of a variable.

```ts
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-view.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-view.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class MyComponent {

  status: boolean = false;

  changeStatus(): void {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = true;
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

**And the HTML**

```html
<div>
  <form #myForm="ngForm">
    <input name="code" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="code" #codeInput="ngModel" required placeholder="Enter your code" />
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5" (click)="changeStatus()">
    <mat-icon aria-label="clear-all" *ngIf="!status">&#xe042;</mat-icon>
    <a>Change status</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <button type="button" class="btn-flat app-btn-flat">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn app-btn" [disabled]="myForm.invalid || myForm.pristine">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I log the value of 'status' in the component. I get the new value of 'true' but it won't change on the view unless I focus the cursor on the input and then click anywhere outside it.

Why is that happening? how can I solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Why is that happening?**

You set `changeDetection` to `OnPush` in one of the ancestor component. That property cannot be overridden. Ref: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

**how can I solve it?**

Unset `changeDetection` in the ancestor component, or manually detect changes like Adam's answer.

```ts
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

changeStatus(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.status = true;
    this._cdr.detectChanges()
  }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're doing it outside of the normal change detection cycle. This will work:

```
export class MyComponent {

  status: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  changeStatus(): void {

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.status = true;
    this._cdr.detectChanges()
  }, 1500);
 }
}
```

**EDIT**: It's updating on your next interaction with the UI because angular is running it's change detection at that point in time and it catches the change in your component and updates the UI. If you're doing things asynchronously (unless you're using angular APIs, like HttpService), then you've got to tell the ChangeDetector that there are changes manually.

Comment: I think you dont need this._cdr.detectChanges() because setTimeout already make angular run change detection